# How do I loop through deeply nested json object

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

```
     var City ={
"City1": [{"name": "Place 1"},{"name": "Place 2"},{"name": "Place 3"}],
"City2":[{"name":"My Place 1"},{"name":"My Place 2"},{"name":"My Place 3"}],
"City3":[{"name":"My Place 1"},{"name":"My Place 2"},{"name":"My Place 3"}]
    };
```

I want to use JavaScript to loop to get the first city name, and then loop to get its places, then get the second city and its places and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `Object.keys()` , `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
var City = {
  "City1": [{
    "name": "Place 1"
  }, {
    "name": "Place 2"
  }, {
    "name": "Place 3"
  }],
  "City2": [{
    "name": "My Place 1"
  }, {
    "name": "My Place 2"
  }, {
    "name": "My Place 3"
  }],
  "City3": [{
    "name": "My Place 1"
  }, {
    "name": "My Place 2"
  }, {
    "name": "My Place 3"
  }]
};

Object.keys(City).forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(value);
  City[value].forEach(function(v, k) {
    console.log(v.name)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `for` loop to go through all properties of the `City` object:

```
for (var key in City) {
    if (City.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var values = City[key];
        // "key" will be City1, City2, ...
        // "values" will be the corresponding array through which
        // you can loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function nestedLoop(obj) {
const res = {};
function recurse(obj, current) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key];
        if(value != undefined) {
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                recurse(value, key);
            } else {
                // Do your stuff here to var value
                res[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
recurse(obj);
return res;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let key in City) {
    let value = City[key];
    console.log(key);
    for (i = 0; i <= value.length; i++) {
      console.log(value[i]);
    }
  }
```